# find the range of the $a$

Tags: calculus

find the range of the $a$ such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{5}x^5+\frac{2}{3}ax^3+x$ be  strictly increasing.

My Try :

$$f'(x)=x^4+2ax^2+1>0  $$

now $a>\dfrac{-(1+x^4)}{2x^2}$

what do i do ?

Comment: no, you should find such $a$ that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$. So, try to think about quadratic polynom properties

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov In general (and here), that $f'(x)=0$ at some points $x$ does not prevent $f$ to be strictly increasing everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

it must be $$x^4+2ax^2+1>0$$ substututing $x^2=t$ we get
$$t^2+2at+a^2+1-a^2>0$$
this is equivalent to
$$(t+a)^2>a^2-1$$
Can you proceed?
you must distinguish the cases $a^2-1<0$ and $a^2-1=0$ and $a^2-1>0$

Comment: "Can you proceed?" Not starting only from what you write. Can you yourself?

Comment: of course i Can, i have added some lines for the OP and for you!

Comment: For me? You could have spared yourself the effort. (By the way, the lines you added merely confirm you do not understand the problem.)

Comment: As usual, one can only wonder that this somehow managed to attract an upvote.

Comment: when you see the real Problem, why will you give not a much better answer?

Comment: Related to the flagrant mistakes in your own post? If not, why even raise the subject instead of correcting the BS you continually post on the site?

Answer (score -1):

First note that $x^2 \geq 0$ for all $x$. 
The discriminant of $x^4 + 2ax^2 + 1$ should be negative, that is $$(2a)^2 - 4(1) < 0$$ or $a^2 - 1 < 0$ which therefore $-1 < a < 1$.
But since $a \geq 0$ satisfy the inequality we have $a > -1 $

Comment: let $a=-1$ now what ?